# How do I remove the BusyIndicator after you read a feed

Tags: qt, symbian, qml

I have a problem with a BusyIndicator, what happens is that I have appointed BusyIndicator that when loading the feed is removed, but in my file. QML images do not appear in the feed, I wonder if there is any way to tell the BusyIndicator that when the image is displayed BusyIndicator remove.

Comment: Hey Vicente, you're going to need be a lot clearer and more specific in order for us to be able to help you - this question doesn't make much sense at the moment! It would be a good idea to include some code to show what you're doing...

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
Image{
   id:remoteImage
   source: "http://www.example.com/m.jpg"

   onProgressChanged: {
   if(progress==1.0)
        busyIndicator.visible=false;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I did this, you can give it a try.

```
Image
{
id : image1
source:"...your source here"
}

BusyIndicator 
{
id:busy1
anchors.centerIn: parent
width:50
height:50
visible: image1.status == Image.Loading 
running: image1.status == Image.Loading 
}
```

//indicator only visible and run when image is loading. After image is being loaded or when Image.Ready, the busy indicator will disappear.